# ASP.Net MVC & EF: Where is not working with PagedList for pagination

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a simple page where i am showing data in tabular format.
i have one search textbox and i want whatever user will write in search textbox that will be filter the data coming from DB. i am using EF and also using PagedList helper in mvc page to show the pagination link.

this area of coding is not working

```
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchText))
        {
            customer = customer.Where(s => s.CompanyName.ToUpper().Contains(SearchText.ToUpper())
            || s.ContactName.ToUpper().Contains(SearchText.ToUpper())
            || s.ContactTitle.ToUpper().Contains(SearchText.ToUpper())
            || s.Address.ToUpper().Contains(SearchText.ToUpper()));
        }
```

here giving full action code for better understand the flow.

```
public ActionResult Index(int? page, string SortColumn, string CurrentSort, String SearchText)
        {
            //var customer = (object) null;
            var customer = from s in db.Customers
                           select s;

            int pageSize = 5;
            int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
            ViewBag.CurrentPage = pageNumber;
            SortColumn = String.IsNullOrEmpty(SortColumn) ? "CompanyName" : SortColumn;
            ViewBag.CurrentSort = SortColumn;
            ViewBag.OldSort = CurrentSort;
            ViewBag.SearchText = SearchText;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchText))
            {
                customer = customer.Where(s => s.CompanyName.ToUpper().Contains(SearchText.ToUpper())
                || s.ContactName.ToUpper().Contains(SearchText.ToUpper())
                || s.ContactTitle.ToUpper().Contains(SearchText.ToUpper())
                || s.Address.ToUpper().Contains(SearchText.ToUpper()));
            }

            switch (SortColumn)
            {
                case "CompanyName":
                    if (SortColumn.Equals(CurrentSort))
                    {
                        customer = customer.OrderByDescending(m => m.CompanyName); //.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);
                        ViewBag.CurrentSort = "";
                    }
                    else
                        customer = customer.OrderBy(m => m.CompanyName); //.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);
                    break;

                case "ContactName":
                    if (SortColumn.Equals(CurrentSort))
                    {
                        customer = db.Customers.OrderByDescending(m => m.ContactName); //.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);
                        ViewBag.CurrentSort = "";
                    }
                    else
                        customer = db.Customers.OrderBy(m => m.ContactName); //.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);
                    break;

                case "ContactTitle":
                    if (SortColumn.Equals(CurrentSort))
                    {
                        customer = db.Customers.OrderByDescending(m => m.ContactTitle); //.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);
                        ViewBag.CurrentSort = "";
                    }
                    else
                        customer = db.Customers.OrderBy(m => m.ContactTitle); //.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);
                    break;

                case "Address":
                    if (SortColumn.Equals(CurrentSort))
                    {
                        customer = db.Customers.OrderByDescending(m => m.Address); //.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);
                        ViewBag.CurrentSort = "";
                    }
                    else
                        customer = db.Customers.OrderBy(m => m.Address); //.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);
                    break;

                case "Default":
                    customer = db.Customers.OrderBy(m => m.CompanyName); //.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);
                    break;
            }

            return View(customer.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));

            //return View(db.Customers.ToList());
        }
```

please tell me where i made the mistake and tell me what to change as a result filter and order should work.

Comment: Step through it with a debugger. Find out what value/values are not what you are expecting them to be

Comment: @musefan i there is problem in approach...that i can understand but not being able to identify where to change the code.

Comment: It is because, you are doing filter first and then applying sorting to the whole table, not on the filtered Customer list.

Comment: For the umpteenth time, **read [ask] and explain what exactly is "not working"**. You should know this, having asked 150 questions. What do you expect to happen, what does actually happen?

Comment: What exception you are having there? edit your question with exception detail. if you are not getting any exception but no result, debug the code to see what your customer object is containing.

Comment: @TazbirBhuiyan no error is coming but filter data is not coming.

Comment: @Mittal please see this ms page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application   they also filter first and then sort data.

Comment: @MonojitSarkar  can you please run a debug session and see what your  'var customer' holds. Debug your code step by step. if you don't have any data there, then resolve that first. if you have data in customer object, please remove filtering and apply them one by one.

Comment: @MonojitSarkar: Yeah but you are only sorting correctly in **one** of your cases... it should always be `customer = customer.OrderBy...` and never `customer = db.Customers.OrderBy...`

Comment: @MonojitSarkar, If you have seen the code properly on "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application" then they do the sorting on the "Student" not on db.Students... In your case you have did it correctly for the first "CompanyName" only.... in others you did the sorting on "db.Customers"

Comment: issue sorted. updated code posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my problem sorted and i change some code. here is fresh working code.

```
public ActionResult Index(int? page, string SortColumn, string CurrentSort, String SearchText)
{
    var customer = (from s in db.Customers
                   // select s;
                   select new CustomerDTO
                    {
                        CompanyName = s.CompanyName,
                        ContactName = s.ContactName,
                        ContactTitle = s.ContactTitle,
                        Address = s.Address,
                    });

    int pageSize = 5;
    int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
    ViewBag.CurrentPage = pageNumber;
    SortColumn = String.IsNullOrEmpty(SortColumn) ? "CompanyName" : SortColumn;
    ViewBag.CurrentSort = SortColumn;
    ViewBag.OldSort = CurrentSort;
    ViewBag.SearchText = SearchText;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchText))
    {
        customer = customer.Where(s => s.CompanyName.ToUpper().Contains(SearchText.ToUpper())
        || s.ContactName.ToUpper().Contains(SearchText.ToUpper())
        || s.ContactTitle.ToUpper().Contains(SearchText.ToUpper())
        || s.Address.ToUpper().Contains(SearchText.ToUpper()));
    }

    switch (SortColumn)
    {
        case "CompanyName":
            if (SortColumn.Equals(CurrentSort))
            {
                customer = customer.OrderByDescending(m => m.CompanyName); 
                ViewBag.CurrentSort = "";
            }
            else
                customer = customer.OrderBy(m => m.CompanyName); 
            break;

        case "ContactName":
            if (SortColumn.Equals(CurrentSort))
            {
                customer = customer.OrderByDescending(m => m.ContactName);
                ViewBag.CurrentSort = "";
            }
            else
                customer = customer.OrderBy(m => m.ContactName); 
            break;

        case "ContactTitle":
            if (SortColumn.Equals(CurrentSort))
            {
                customer = customer.OrderByDescending(m => m.ContactTitle); 
                ViewBag.CurrentSort = "";
            }
            else
                customer = customer.OrderBy(m => m.ContactTitle); 
            break;

        case "Address":
            if (SortColumn.Equals(CurrentSort))
            {
                customer = customer.OrderByDescending(m => m.Address); 
                ViewBag.CurrentSort = "";
            }
            else
                customer = customer.OrderBy(m => m.Address); 
            break;

        case "Default":
            customer = customer.OrderBy(m => m.CompanyName); 
            break;
    }

    return View(customer.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
}
```

### Razor view code

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<MVCCRUDPageList.Models.CustomerDTO>
@using PagedList.Mvc;


@section csssection {
    <link href="~/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


    <style>
        .form-gap {
            margin-bottom: 15px;
        }
    </style>
}

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>List of Customers</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Customers", new { page = ViewBag.CurrentPage, SortColumn = ViewBag.CurrentSort, CurrentSort = ViewBag.OldSort }))
{
<div class="row form-gap">
    <div class="input-group col-xs-5 col-lg-4">
       @Html.TextBox("SearchText", null, new { @class= "form-control"})
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-search btn-info" id="submit">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                <span class="label-icon">Search</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="input-group col-xs-5 col-lg-8">
    </div>
</div>
}


<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @*@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().CompanyName)*@

                @Html.ActionLink("Company", "Index",
                                                        new { page = ViewBag.CurrentPage, SortColumn = "CompanyName", CurrentSort = ViewBag.CurrentSort, SearchText = ViewBag.SearchText })
            </th>

            <th>
                @*@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().ContactName)*@
                @Html.ActionLink("Name", "Index",
                                              new { page = ViewBag.CurrentPage, SortColumn = "ContactName", CurrentSort = ViewBag.CurrentSort, SearchText = ViewBag.SearchText })
            </th>

            <th>
                @*@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().ContactTitle)*@
                @Html.ActionLink("Title", "Index",
                                              new { page = ViewBag.CurrentPage, SortColumn = "ContactTitle", CurrentSort = ViewBag.CurrentSort, SearchText = ViewBag.SearchText })
            </th>

            <th>
                @*@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().Address)*@
                @Html.ActionLink("Address", "Index",
                                              new { page = ViewBag.CurrentPage, SortColumn = "Address", CurrentSort = ViewBag.CurrentSort, SearchText = ViewBag.SearchText })
            </th>


            <th class="text-center">Action</th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CompanyName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ContactName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ContactTitle)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address)
                </td>


                <td class="text-center">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.CustomerID, page = ViewBag.CurrentPage }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.CustomerID, page = ViewBag.CurrentPage }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.CustomerID, page = ViewBag.CurrentPage })
                </td>
            </tr>
            }

    </table>

</div>

@if(Model.Count>0)
{
    @: Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount / (Total Records:  @Model.TotalItemCount)

    @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page, SortColumn = ViewBag.CurrentSort, CurrentSort = ViewBag.OldSort, SearchText = ViewBag.SearchText }), PagedListRenderOptions.OnlyShowFivePagesAtATime)
}
```